# SingleTapOnMap method not calling in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, mapbox

I am using below piece of code using to interact with MBTiles. But singleTapOnMap method is not calling when i run it on iphone. I also added Trailer which is working on TileMill, but not on iPhone. Whether i have gone wrong anywhere?

//ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<RMMapViewDelegate>

@end
```

//ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    RMMBTilesSource *offlineSource = [[RMMBTilesSource alloc] initWithTileSetResource:@"MYMAP" ofType:@"mbtiles"];

    RMMapView *mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:offlineSource];

    mapView.zoom = 2;

    mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    mapView.adjustTilesForRetinaDisplay = YES; // these tiles aren't designed specifically for retina, so make them legible

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];

}

#pragma mark -

- (void)singleTapOnMap:(RMMapView *)mapView at:(CGPoint)point
{
    [mapView removeAllAnnotations];

    RMMapBoxSource *source = (RMMapBoxSource *)mapView.tileSource;


    NSLog(@"You tapped at %f, %f", [mapView pixelToCoordinate:point].latitude, [mapView pixelToCoordinate:point].longitude);

    if ([source conformsToProtocol:@protocol(RMInteractiveSource)] && [source supportsInteractivity])
        {
        NSString *formattedOutput = [source formattedOutputOfType:RMInteractiveSourceOutputTypeTeaser
                                                         forPoint:point
                                                        inMapView:mapView];

        if (formattedOutput && [formattedOutput length])
            {
            // parse the country name out of the content
            //
            NSUInteger startOfCountryName = [formattedOutput rangeOfString:@"<strong>"].location + [@"<strong>" length];
            NSUInteger endOfCountryName   = [formattedOutput rangeOfString:@"</strong>"].location;

            NSString *countryName = [formattedOutput substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startOfCountryName, endOfCountryName - startOfCountryName)];

            // parse the flag image out of the content
            //
            NSUInteger startOfFlagImage = [formattedOutput rangeOfString:@"base64,"].location + [@"base64," length];
            NSUInteger endOfFlagImage   = [formattedOutput rangeOfString:@"\" style"].location;

            UIImage *flagImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:[formattedOutput substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startOfFlagImage, endOfFlagImage)]]];

            RMAnnotation *annotation = [RMAnnotation annotationWithMapView:mapView coordinate:[mapView pixelToCoordinate:point] andTitle:countryName];

            annotation.userInfo = flagImage;

            [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

            [mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
            }
        }
}


- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation
{

    RMMarker *marker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithMapBoxMarkerImage:@"embassy"];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 32)];

    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    imageView.image = annotation.userInfo;

    marker.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imageView;

    marker.canShowCallout = YES;

    return marker;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: you are missing `mapView.delegate = self;` in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the delegate protocol:

```
mapView.delegate = self;
```